# Adding ssl certificate for local development with docker

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, docker-compose

I want to add a certificate for local development with the help of a docker.

Did under this article https://codewithhugo.com/docker-compose-local-https/.

But it turned out that I have my main nginx and also added this nginx proxy, which using certificates transfers requests for https to my nginx.

My docker compose looks like this:

```
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ./storage/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
    depends_on:
      - web

  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: docker/dev/web.Dockerfile
    image: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_web
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_web_1
    ports:
      - "8089:80"
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: ${VIRTUAL_HOST}
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 8089
    depends_on:
      - app
    links:
      - 'app:app'
```

My nginx.conf:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        index index.php index.html;
        root /var/www/public;

        access_log /dev/stdout;
        error_log /dev/stdout debug;

        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass app:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }
    }
```

Is it normal to do this so that there are two nginx? (for production, as I understand it, it’s definitely not, but for local development, it’s more interesting)

Comment: Can you add your nginx config? that is the nginx config that will configure ssl, docker wil just make them available for use

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: you missed in nginx config, to redirect to https

Comment: No, in this config everything is working.

Comment: The question was, is it right way to use two nginx in local development or better use 1 nginx?

Comment: better to use one, and use proxy to redirect traffic, this is why nginx for. for routing and balacning

Comment: the above config will only work for HTTP, not for https, to add https support you to update config